# How to use multiple settimeout function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, settimeout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome page</h1>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      // after 2 seconds
      window.location = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      // after 5 seconds
      window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
    }, 5000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While I am running html page after 2 seconds redirecting to w3school.com but after 5 seconds it is not going to stackoverflow.com, how can I run both?

Comment: Once you redirect to another page, all JavaScript from the original page stops.

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: anyother suggestion how to do

Comment: After the first `timeout` the user has already gone to w3schools, there's no way to achieve this.

Comment: <script>
  setTimeout(function () {
     // after 2 seconds
     window.location = "/next-page";
  }, 2000)
</script>
//nodejs
app.get('/thankyou',function(req,res){
    res.render('thankyou' {message : 'Thank you for your submission'});
});

Comment: if i write like this\

Answer (score 0):

Once you redirect from one page to the other you destroy the context for the page and the second timeout will never fire. If you want to scroll through a bunch of pages you will need to use an iframe so that the page stays loaded and puts the target in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!!
*Using IFrame .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome page</h1>
  <iframe id="myFrame" src="#"></iframe>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      // after 2 seconds
     document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      // after 5 seconds
      document.getElementById("myFrame").src ="https://stackoverflow.com/";
    }, 5000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use window.open to open in a new browser tab while keeping the instance of same page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <body>
    <h1>Welcome page</h1>
 </body>

 </html>
```

```
let w3Timer = setTimeout(function() {
   // after 2 seconds
   window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/");
   // Stop timer from infinite running.
   clearTimeout(w3Timer);
}, 2000);

let stTimer = setTimeout(function() {
   // after 5 seconds
   window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/");
   clearTimeout(stTimer)
}, 5000);
```